# Change Date Authored in file downloaded

Tags: java, file-io, java-io, android-file

I'm downloading a video from a server and store it on android storage. I'm using Android Studio java. Everything is okay but there is a parameter "Date Authored" with a weird value past (a date before the file created).

Here is a detail of that file:

[image: Properties>Details of affected file]

This problem occurs randomly. I'm not sure why it happens.

This file detail in which everything is fine:

[image: file with proper properties>Details]

**EDIT:**

After a few research, I found data is not actually wrong it is the date when the particular video is uploaded on the server. So

My question is:
**Is it possible to download the only video without their meta-data from the server?**

For any classification ask me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MP4 files contain meta-data, such as "Title" and "Date Authored". They are values inside the file.

File systems also store meta-data about files, such as "Date Created" and "Date Modified". These are maintained by the Operating System (Windows, Linux, ...).

It seems that the property dialog you're looking at has a quirk. It is always displaying a "Date Authored", even when not found in the file, in which case it defaults the value to be the same as "Date Created".

It's a **quirk** of the dialog, and you should just ignore it / learn to live with it.

But to answer your question: Yes, you can modify the "Date Authored" value, if you have Java code that can read/write the property meta-data of an MP4 formatted file.

Search the web to see if there is a library for that, if you really feel the need for it. I wouldn't bother.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But I want to find why this problem occurs. It is a new file created on my device but has an old "Authored date". Due to this newly downloaded video not appearing as first in the gallery and not on social media my new video is at last.

Comment: That's not an answer. It would be a great comment though. Write it as a comment to the question (you have the 50 rep needed for that), then delete this answer to clear the negative rep it is giving you. –

Comment: @Alays It is an answer to *why* it only happens sometimes, and an answer to whether it is *possible* to alter the "Date Authored" value via code. It is also too long to be a comment, even if I was inclined to agree with you, which I don't.

Comment: @Udhayarajan *"It is a new file created on my device"* + *"newly downloaded video"* = "it is a 2-year old file that was downloaded today". As I already explained in the answer, the "Date Authored" value is stored inside the file and represents the date the file *content* was created (authored) and is not modified by the OS, unlike the "Date Created" value with is modified by the OS and represents the date the local file itself was created on your device, and says nothing about the file content.